# View elements do not display correctly in small screens

Tags: android, layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".LearningFragment">
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_fragments_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_top"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation" >
        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/countLearningWord"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Осталось 0 слов"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="18sp"/>
            <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:scaleType="fitStart"
                    tools:scaleType="fitXY" />
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textEnglish"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/english"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
                    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Button"/>
                    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Button"/>
                    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Button"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
                    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button4"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Button" />
                    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button5"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Button"/>
                    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button6"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Button"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>  
</FrameLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdmMJ.png)

I don’t fully understand how to do responsive design, but they use dp in all sources, but google says that it’s not recommended to use it, here I used LinerLayout with its wonderful android: layout_weight, but it also doesn’t work correctly, what should I do?

I read the recommendation from other sources, but this did not give the correct result: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: Use `constraint layout`/ `Relative layout`

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a ScrollView, the cases in which you need to list your views vertically, you need to take into count that the views can not be fit always like the image you shared. So just use this code below

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LearningFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_fragments_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_top">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/countLearningWord"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Осталось 0 слов"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:scaleType="fitStart"
                    tools:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textEnglish"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/english"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Button" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Button" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Button" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button4"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Button" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button5"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Button" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button6"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Button" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes, I agree in some cases, using scroll is indispensable, but it's better to sacrifice the size of ImageView than to use such a solution